# REPEATED in SPSS linear mixed model

Tags: spss, mixed-models

I am anlyzing data from an experiment.

I have three groups ( GROUP, 1 between subject factor) to compare via a cognitive task.

Task is composed by a 3 way full factorial design (2x3x3); all subjects are presented two stimuli (factor1), for each stimulus there are three conditions (factor2), and for each condition three position on the screen (factor3). For each combination of factors, there are N trials that are averaged to give average accuracy (ACC) and average reaction time (RT).

I want to build a model in spss using linear mixed model.

I tried in SPSS 22 the following syntax:

```
MIXED ACC BY GROUP FACTOR1 FACTOR2 FACTOR3 GENDER WITH RT Age

/FIXED = GROUP FACTOR1 FACTOR2 FACTOR3 GROUP*FACTOR1 GROUP*FACTOR2 GROUP*FACTOR3 GENDER AGE RT | SSTYPE(3)

/RANDOM= INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(SUBID) COVTYPE(VC)
```

Considered I have averaged accuracy rates across trials for each combination, should I include a repeated statement as well? If this were the case,  what is the difference between the following

```
/REPEATED= FACTOR1 FACTOR2 FACTOR3 | SUBJECT(SUBID) COVTYPE(UN)
```

and the following nomenclature?

```
/REPEATED= FACTOR1*FACTOR2*FACTOR3 | SUBJECT(SUBID) COVTYPE(UN)
```

In other words, what is the difference between including or less asterisks?

Thanks for your comments,

Alessandro

Comment: You are right eli, I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions here: (1) a statistical question about what type of analysis is appropriate, and (2) a code question.

(1) Very briefly, if you're going to use linear mixed models, I think you should use all the data, and not average across your N trials within each combination of factors.  Those N trials are your repeated measurements.

(2) The IBM KnowledgeCenter page on the [REPEATED subcommand](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.reference/spss/advanced/syn_mixed_repeated.htm) states

> Specify a list of variable names (of any type) connected by asterisks
>   (repeated measure) following the REPEATED subcommand.

which suggests that

```
/REPEATED= FACTOR1 FACTOR2 FACTOR3 | SUBJECT(SUBID) COVTYPE(UN)
```

should be a syntax error.  It isn't, so I looked at the Model Information table in the output.  For both REPEATED specifications, the Repeated Effects section of that table lists FACTOR1*FACTOR2*FACTOR3 as the effect.

Based on this, it's safe to say that the SPSS syntax parser interprets

```
/REPEATED= FACTOR1 FACTOR2 FACTOR3 | SUBJECT(SUBID) COVTYPE(UN)
```

to be equivalent to

```
/REPEATED= FACTOR1*FACTOR2*FACTOR3 | SUBJECT(SUBID) COVTYPE(UN)
```